# Import Debian Package descriptions into OWL/RDF ontology using PERL

Tags: perl, debian, semantic-web, ontology

I have a Protege (RDF/OWL) Ontology of a Debian Package Management System. The Ontology is structured as follows:

Class: Package
Datatype Properties: 
Name 
architecture
section
version
distribution

Object Properties:
predepends
enhances
recommends
suggests

How can I use Perl to execute an algorithm that will automatically import Package Descriptions from the Debian website as instances of my Ontology.

I am totally new to Perl language and also Ontologies. Looking forward to some tips.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a simple enough ontology you may as well just work in pure RDF.  I've heard good things about [RDF::Trine](http://search.cpan.org/~gwilliams/RDF-Trine-0.135/).  See [RDF Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax/) as well.  Looks like CPAN has quite a few modules relating to Debian packages http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=Debian

http://answers.semanticweb.com is another great resource for semantic web related questions.

Comment: thanks for the links. very helpful indeed. my guide has mentioned to use RDF:Redland. have u used RDF:Redland and is it similar to Trine or Primer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ONTO-PERL](http://p3rl.org/ONTO-PERL)?  It uses its own format, OBO, for ontologies, but provides scripts to convert to and from OWL.

The other piece is parsing the debian package information; that's just a matter of doing it.  Have you made a start at it and run into trouble?  (It's not a bad project for a new-to-Perl programmer, but maybe not so good if you have a tight timeframe.)

Comment: hello, thank you for your response. No I have not yet begun the programming part. Yes there is time constraint. I have around two weeks to finish the whole job. I have not looked into ONTO-PERL. Infact, I am supposed to use RDF:Redland. But I will try to figure out ONTO-PERL's utility in this project.